# Estructura app android

Tags: android, android-layout

He instalado Android Studio para crear mi primera aplicación Android. Tengo dudas sobre la estructura. Entiendo que la base de datos la tendría que tener en local o alojarla donde yo quiera, y desde la aplicación se programarán las pantallas y los accesos a base de datos, ¿voy bien? Como base de datos me imagino que pondré SQLite, que es sencilla y he visto en foros que funciona bien. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La estructura mínima de una app de Android contiene los siguientes archivos:

./AndroidManifest.xml

```
Indica metadata del proyecto, permisos, actividades, servicios e intentos.
```

./ActividadPrincipal.java

```
Aquí va el código principal de tu aplicación.
```

./actividadPrincipal.xml

```
Aquí se encuentra el código de tu intefaz. Formularios, textos, imagenes...
```

Es común tener varios archivos .java o usar kotlin en su lugar para tener organizado el programa en múltiples clases y archivos.

A parte de estos ficheros, también es común tener mutiples archivos .xml que guarden información de strings, interfaces, etc.

Otro tipo de archivos básicos que vas a encontrar en casi todas las apps, son los iconos. Normalmente los mismos en múltiples resoluciones para que se adapten bien a cualquier dispositivo.

También es común tener en la carpeta assets cualquier tipo de archivo que el programa necesite. Por ejemplo archivos de texto, html o markdown con menus de ayuda para el programa, etc.

Aquì tienes una apk muy básica con varios de estos ficheros que utilizo de plantilla para que puedas revisar el contenido de los archivos. https://github.com/StringManolo/APKGeneratorBase

La base de datos puedes tenerla en memoria (si le pones de nombre Null), en local (si le das nombre) o en remoto (a través de un servidor web por ejemplo), depende de las necesidades y características de tu aplicación.

[www.develou.com/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/](http://www.develou.com/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/)